# Arithmetic functions on short exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ of abelian groups or modules over a fixed ring $R$ or complexes of modules over $R$. Denote abelian group category or module category as $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $f$ be a function defined on objects $\mathcal{C}$ with the range say real number s.t. the followings hold.

1.If $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$ with $A\cong B$ then $f(A)=f(B)$.(i.e. $f$ recognizes only quasi-isomoprhims.)

2. If $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, then $f(A)+f(C)=f(B)$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the classification of such $f$'s? How many distinct such $f$ exist?(It is clear I can scale $f$ by any non-zero real number. In this case, I treat them as the same.) Consider hilbert polynomials of modules(as eventual stabilization of component) as one of such example but with values over $Z$ or rank of vector spaces over a field.

$\textbf{Q':}$ Is there such a function to rings in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually completely classify such functions. I'm going to cheat and assume this is a small category. Take the real vector space with basis the objects of the category, and take the quotient by the subspace generated by $B-A-C$ for all such short exact sequences. Then the functions you want are simply elements of the dual of this quotient space.

Comment: Maybe this is a really dumb question. Do I knew this dual space even finitely generated in general? The vector space case should be relatively easy as all finite dimensional vector spaces are classified by their ranks. This statement might be strange for non finite dimensional vector space. So I think for this case, there is only one then. But for general rings, I do not see this holds in full generality.

Comment: @user Unless the category is finite, it's never finite dimensional. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Every such $f$ is zero : indeed for any object $M$ in $C$, you have an exact sequence $$0\to \bigoplus_\mathbb{N}M\to \bigoplus_\mathbb{N}M\to M\to 0$$ which gives $f(M)+ a = a$, so $f(M) = 0$.

Comment: I am not sure this is true. Consider the objects as vector spaces over any field and $f$ as rank. Here I need to say $f(V)=\infty$ for infinite dimensional vector space $V$.

Comment: And your statement is basically asserting non-existence of hilbert polynomial after component stabilization.

Comment: Well you said $f$ was taking real values, you didn't mention it could take infinite values as well

Comment: Then it is my sloppiness. When I was thinking about this, I had context of coherent sheaves which automatically removes infinity.